# How to make react-hook-form work with multiple forms in one page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I am using react-hook-form in my project and I have 2 totally separate forms, but when I submit one of the forms and if some fields in the other form is required I can't submit the current form, check the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-validation-onblur-czzru), and try to submit one of the form, the forms should work independently of each other but it looks like they depend on each other.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You are using the same hook instance for both forms. You will have to reuse with different names.

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const {
    register,
    formState: { errors },
    handleSubmit,
  } = useForm({
    mode: "onBlur",
  });

  const {
    register: register2,
    formState: { errors: errors2 },
    handleSubmit: handleSubmit2,
  } = useForm({
    mode: "onBlur",
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  };

  const onSubmitEmail = (data) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form key={1} onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
          <input
            name="firstName"
            placeholder="bill"
            ref={register({ required: true })}
          />
          {errors.firstName && <p>This is required</p>}
        </div>

        <div>
          <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
          <input
            name="lastName"
            placeholder="luo"
            ref={register({ required: true })}
          />
          {errors.lastName && <p>This is required</p>}
        </div>
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>

      <form key={2} onSubmit={handleSubmit2(onSubmitEmail)}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="email" placeholder="bluebill1049@hotmail.com">
            Email
          </label>
          <input name="email" ref={register2({ required: true })} />
          {errors2.email && <p>This is required</p>}
        </div>
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: If you are using react-hook-form older than V7. Please see edit history by Sibiraj.

Comment: did you notice ? the guy @bill who commented is the creator of react use form.

Comment: @Eddysapata  LOL I didn't, I thought it's the person who asked the question. Bill has got good success with the package. It's an amazing piece of work indeed.

Comment: do we need these within the form tags? `key={1}` and `key={2}`???

Comment: Most important thing to note here is the `key={1}` and `key={2}`

Answer (score 12):

Quick update to Faizaan's answer: in my case, `errors` should be used with `formState`, not by itself. Therefore, the property should be imported as:

```
const { formState: { errors } } = useForm();
const { formState: { errors: errors2 } } = useForm();
```

The names might be confusing, but these is the solution that I arrived at.

Comment: From version 7 onwards.

Comment: Is it possible to create multiple forms dynamically on a page? This hard codes 2 forms? can we have a list of react-hook-forms created dynamically and rendered on the page?

Comment: I've been trying to do that very thing, @MarkRedman, but I've not yet had success.  There are rules for hooks that make it not so straightforward.  Granted, I've started using React only a couple months ago, so others would know better.

Comment: @benJephunneh I cant remember how I did this, was also new to React.js... In react, just think component, so create a new component with 1 form, then just render multiple components..

Answer (score 1):

As a (slightly) more expandable way of doing this, you can wrap the context hook in a function and use that to repeat-register:

```js
export default function Page() {

    // Wrap the hook in a function
    const registerForm = () => {
        const { register, formState, handleSubmit } = useForm();
        return { register, formState, handleSubmit };
    }

    // Register multiple forms
    const forms = {
        email: registerForm(),
        delivery: registerForm(),
        payment: registerForm(),
    }

....
```

Then, just use the props from each `registerForm` const:

```js
// Form 1
<form onSubmit={forms.email.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  <Text
    id="email"
    register={forms.email.register}
    formState={forms.email.formState}
    validation={{required: 'Email address is required'}}
  />
  <Submit />
</form>

// Form 2
<form onSubmit={forms.delivery.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  <Text
    id="email"
    register={forms.delivery.register}
    formState={forms.delivery.formState}
    validation={{required: 'Delievery address is required'}}
  />
  <Submit />
</form>

... etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is using useForm with other libraries like Material UI and have two forms then can be used:

```
const { control, handleSubmit } = useForm({
resolver: yupResolver(schema), })

const { control: control2, handleSubmit: handleSubmitReset } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema2),
  });


  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

 const onSubmitResend = async (data) => {
        console.log(data);
      };
```

And the forms will look like:

FORM-1

```
<form key={1} onSubmit={handleSubmitReset(onSubmitResend)}>
          <FormLabel
            component="legend"
            color="secondary"
            sx={{ color: "#fff", pt: 2 }}
          >
            Email:
          </FormLabel>
          <Controller
            defaultValue=""
            name="email"
            control={control2}
            render={({
              field: { onChange, value },
              fieldState: { error },
            }) => (
              <TextField
                helperText={error ? error.message : null}
                error={!!error}
                value={value}
                onChange={onChange}
                id="outlined-basic"
                placeholder="Enter Email address"
                variant="outlined"
                fullWidth
                color="secondary"
                InputProps={{
                  style: {
                    color: "#fff",
                    border: "1px solid #fff",
                    borderRadius: "32px",
                    marginTop: "16px",
                  },
                }}
              />
            )}
          />

          >
            <Button
              fullWidth
              color="secondary"
              type="submit">
               Submit
            </Button>
        </form>
```

FORM-2

```
 <form key={2} onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <FormLabel
            component="legend"
            color="secondary"
            sx={{ color: "#fff", pt: 2 }}
          >
            Email:
          </FormLabel>
          <Controller
            defaultValue=""
            name="email"
            control={control}
            render={({
              field: { onChange, value },
              fieldState: { error },
            }) => (
              <TextField
                helperText={error ? error.message : null}
                error={!!error}
                value={value}
                onChange={onChange}
                id="outlined-basic"
                placeholder="Enter Email address"
                variant="outlined"
                fullWidth
                color="secondary"
                InputProps={{
                  style: {
                    color: "#fff",
                    border: "1px solid #fff",
                    borderRadius: "32px",
                    marginTop: "16px",
                  },
                }}
              />
            )}
          />

          >
            <Button
              fullWidth
              color="secondary"
              type="submit">
               Submit
            </Button>
        </form>
```