# react-hook-form form in form

Tags: reactjs, forms, submit

I used react-hook-form and I have a small issue. I have a form into a modal and another from into another modal => form in form. My problem is that when I submit the second form the first form is triggering.

I want to trigger the second from and go back to first form.

Comment: You should add your component/app code. We can't help you if we can't see the code and how your implementation is working.

Comment: It might be unrelated to RHF since [nested forms are not valid HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-form-element)

Answer (score 1):

If you have to deal with multiple forms with react hook form you can use multiple useForm instances (one for each form, with different handlers):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60277873/10707366, taken from this answer:

```
  const { register, errors, handleSubmit } = useForm({
    mode: "onBlur"
  });

  const {
    register: register2,
    errors: errors2,
    handleSubmit: handleSubmit2
  } = useForm({
    mode: "onBlur"
  });
```