# How to pass methods to form provider with different name to handle nested forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

As mentioned in [#60277873](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60277873), in order to create nested forms you must rename the methods of the nested form such as :

```
const {
    register,
    formState: { errors },
    handleSubmit,
  } = useForm({
    mode: "onBlur",
  });
```

becomes :

```
  const {
    register: register2,
    formState: { errors: errors2 },
    handleSubmit: handleSubmit2,
  } = useForm({
    mode: "onBlur",
  });
```

However, I need to use the [FormProvider](https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage#FormProviderPerformance) and I don't know how to pass methods and modify the name of the methods since we can't do :

```
<FormProvider {register: register2, formState: { errors: errors2 }, handleSubmit: handleSubmit2 }>
```

Has anyone already encountered this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code of `react-hook-form` I don't think you can do this out of the box, unless you create your own contexts and hooks
Something like this:

```
const MyFormCtxDefaults = {
    form1: null,
    form2: null,
};
const MyFormCtx = React.createContext(MyFormCtxDefaults);
const MyFormCtxProvider = (props) =>
    (<MyFormCtx.Provider value={props}>{children}</MyFormCtx.Provider>);

const useMyForm = () => React.useContext(MyFormCtx);

const MyForm = () => {
    const form1 = useForm(...);
    const form2 = useForm(...);

    return (
        <MyFormCtxProvider form1={form1} form2={form2}>
            <MyForm1 />
            <MyForm2 />
        </MyFormCtxProvider>
    );
};

const MyForm1 = () => {
    const {register} = useMyForm().form1;

    return (
        <input {...register('foo')} />
    );
};

const MyForm2 = () => {
    const {register} = useMyForm().form2;

    return (
        <input {...register('bar')} />
    );
};
```

It's going to be a pain to maintain typescript tough, for help please see the original implementation https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/master/src/useFormContext.tsx#L4

Comment: Thanks for the details, i'll try to sort something out of this and let you know how I did as soon as I solved this!